# Check code before submitting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I've made an iptables script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Kaveen's TCP Redirect SCRIPT"
clear
read -p "Port:" port
echo ""
read -p "Customer IP:" cusip
echo ""
read -p "Your Filtered IP:" filip
echo ""
read -p "Your Secondary IP:" secip
echo "Generating TCP Redirect on port $port from your ip $filip to customer      ip $cusip"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $filip --dport $port -j DNAT --to-    destination $cusip
echo "TCP Redirect 1/2 OK"
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
echo "TCP Redirect 2/2 OK"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $cusip -j SNAT --to-source $secip
echo "Better Traffic Movement rule 1/1 OK"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source $filip
echo "Player Movement Rule 1/1 OK"
echo "Generating reset script...."
echo "#!/bin/sh" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
chmod +x reset.sh
echo "Reset script creation OK"
echo "Reset script can be used via ./reset.sh in directory:"
pwd
echo "TCP Redirect made from $fillip to $cusip on port $port"
```

Now as you can see, there's a bunch of iptables commands in there, I'd like a function, or some way I can CHECK those commands, and if something goes wrong.

it returns FAILED, I'd also like a way to check that the input people put for "Port" "Customer IP" are PORTS and IP addresses, not letters, words, but properly formated IPs and port (for the first one)

Comment: Shouldn't you check your input (port and ip address) first, in order to *prevent* failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ip route get` to help decide if the input is a valid IP address, assuming your machine should be able to route to everything.  It will fail if you pass it something other than an IP.

For the port, you could test if it's a positive integer fairly easily like

```
if [[ $port =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "It's a non-negative int!"
fi
```

If you want to know if it falls into a valid port range, you could then test if it's in a range you want, like

```
if [[ $port -gt 0 && $port -lt 65535 ]]; then
    echo "Port is probably OK"
fi
```

There may be an easier way to check the IP part, but if you aren't willing to accept strings that look like IPs but have invalid values (i.e., octets greater than 255) it gets hairy checking them, but checking if the system would know how to try to get a packet to the IP is a quick 'n' dirty stand in for me at least.

One can use the success or failure of any command, `ip route get` in this case, in an `if` just like so:

```
if ip route get $cusip &>/dev/null; then
    echo "$cusip is an address I know how to route to"
else
    echo "I either didn't know what $cusip is or don't know how to get there"
fi
```

I added the `&>/dev/null` to hide the output of the command since we don't care what it says, we just want to know if if succeeded or failed.

Comment: How would I plug in the ip route get into an if statement ?

Comment: After the ELSE, where it says I dont know how to get there, how do I call an exit and stop the script?

Comment: just an "exit" on another line after the echo?

Comment: Yes, you can run any command you like in those blocks, including `exit` if you want to exit the script

Comment: ./loltest.sh: 5: ./loltest.sh: [[: not found
Invalid port
why do I get this? When I put in your port syntax for if

Comment: @KaveenK I hadn't noticed your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` the `[[` syntax is `bash` only.  Can you use `#!/bin/bash` instead, or do you need a POSIX solution?

Comment: I fixed that, I'm not familiar with bash, is it possible for you give me a shell solution? or tell me what's different in bash Also, I'm having other problems, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932236/whats-wrong-with-this-if-statement